# Redirect with id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to Redirect to a route:

```
return Redirect::route('job_view', array('id' =>$id))
                ->with('succes','Alread Apply for this post');
```

> Error :InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314
>           Route [job_view] not defined.

The route Define in **Web.php**

```
Route::get('/job_view/{id}','jobseekerController@job_view');
```

Comment: how you define job_view route in web.php can you give it here

Comment: Route::get('/job_view/{id}','jobseekerController@job_view');

Comment: do it like this `Route::get('/job_view/{id}','jobseekerController@job_view')->name('job_view');`

Answer (score 5):

In your web definition you defined Id but when you were calling the redirect to the job_view, you did not add the id to it. Do this instead

```
return redirect()->to('job_view/'.$id);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can pass parameter and some status like this

```
return Redirect::to('job_view')
->with(['id'=>$id,'succes' => 'Alread Apply for this post']);
```

`['id'=>$id,'succes' => 'Alread Apply for this post']` thats mean you pass two parameters first `id` and second is `succes` and then you get in view like this

for id: `{{$id}}`

for succes: `{{$succes}}`

Comment: Need to redirect with Id   but id redirect  like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/job_view

Comment: i have mention `'id'=>$id`

Comment: i have update my answer with more details .. i think this detail will help you

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your route in your web.php file like that.

```
Route::get('/job_view/{id}', ['as' => 'job_view', 'uses' => 'jobseekerController@job_view']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `route()` method, you need to define route name:

```
Route::get('/job_view/{id}', 'jobseekerController@job_view')->name('job_view');
```

Or:

```
Route::get('/job_view/{id}', ['as' => 'job_view', 'uses' => 'jobseekerController@job_view']);
```